# C makefile ? : linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: c, makefile, compilation

I have been struggling to make a make file... 
In my folder I have

```
main.c mix.c mix.h Makefile
```

What should I write in the makefile in order to compile like this :

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -std=c99 -O1 -o main *.c
```

and test my code using

```
./main
```

I have copied a makefile but it gives me this error :

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_mix", referenced from:
  _main in main-d5c713.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see 
invocation)
make: *** [main] Error 1
```

This is my makefile

```
CC=gcc
CPPFLAGS= -MMD
CFLAGS= -Wall -Wextra -std=c99 -O2
LDFLAGS=
LDLIBS=

SRC= main.c
DEP= ${SRC:.c=.d}
PRG= ${SRC:.c=}

all: ${PRG}

-include ${DEP}

clean:
    rm -f *.o
    rm -f ${DEP}
    rm -f ${PRG}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

1. In your `Makefile`, you list only *one* source file. You need to list *all* that are used to build your program. I.e. you need to have e.g.

   ```
   SRC = main.c mix.c
   ```

   Here you should list all the *source* files needed to build your program.
2. Right now you attempt to build each listed source file into its own separate program. Drop the `PRG` variable and instead do something like

   ```
   OBJ = ${SRC:.c=.o}

   all: main

   main: ${OBJ}
   ```

   This will create a variable `OBJ` which will list the object files needed (created from the `SRC` variable). Then the `main` target list the object files that it depends on and the `make` command should link all the object files to form the `main` executable program.

Comment: could you please explain what you did, and shall I remove all but your code?

Comment: @whohasfriends3 *Change* the parts I show in your own existing `Makefile`.

Comment: do I need to include the mix.h file in SRC ?

Comment: @whohasfriends3 No that should be handled by the `DEP` variable and the `-include {DEP}` part